# How get permission for specific folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make a **tool** for , but **I can't access its directory** `Com.tool.mobile` in `Android/data`

Full Path: `/Android/data/Com.tool.mobile`

Tried Nothing (Because I am new I don't know much coding.

**Q:** How to access *this* specfic folder `Com.tool.mobile` of `android/data`

like this app:

1. [Screenshot: Error - Special Permission is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBUjI.jpg)
2. [Screenshot: Dialog - Allow Tool to access files in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQbl3.jpg)
3. [App Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.tsoml.graphicssettings)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! One tip: There are [formating tips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Dont worry I edited your post for you it may soon be visible.

Comment: `Full Path :/Android/data/Com.pubg.krmobile` That is not a full path to begin with. Please try again.

Comment: can you give me example (Full Path)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

okay so all of these people saying you cannot access app specific folders, are absolutely wrong, heres how u do it:

Step 1: get the permission of the folder you want,

```
public void openDirectory() {

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.pubg.krmobile/whatever folder you want to access";
File file = new File(path);
String startDir, secondDir, finalDirPath;

if (file.exists()) {
    startDir = "Android%2Fdata%2Fcom.pubg.krmobile%2Fthefilder%2Fsubfolder%2Fdeepersubfolder";
} 

StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();


Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");

String scheme = uri.toString();

Log.d("TAG", "INITIAL_URI scheme: " + scheme);

scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");

finalDirPath = scheme + "%3A" + startDir;

uri = Uri.parse(finalDirPath);

intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);

Log.d("TAG", "uri: " + uri.toString());

try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, 6);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {

}}
```

step 2: write an onactivityresult to get the path

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            if (uri.getPath().endsWith(".Statuses")) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult: " + uri.getPath());
                final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
                                              & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
                }
                
                // these are my SharedPerfernce values for remembering the path
                prefHelper.setIsScopePermissionGranted(true);
                prefHelper.setSavedRoute(uri.toString());
                
                // save any boolean in pref if user given the right path so we can use the path 
                // in future and avoid to ask permission more than one time
                
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainDashboardActivity.class));
                finish();
                
            } else {
                // dialog when user gave wrong path
                showWrongPathDialog();
            }
            
        }
    }}
```

step 3: Get the files one by one from here

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            // uri is the path which we've saved in our shared pref
            DocumentFile fromTreeUri = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
            DocumentFile[] documentFiles = fromTreeUri.listFiles();
            
            
            for (int i = 0; i < documentFiles.length; i++) {
                documentFiles[i].getUri().toString() //uri of the document
                }
            }
        }
```

and voila, you now have access to that folder using the path saved in shared prefrences

Comment: step 3 just list file entries. how to read and write those files ?

Comment: @KnIfER this gives you the file URI, you can use that URI and open the file using "file" class in android. Note that you wont be able to use scoped storage with android 10, for android 10, scoped storage is optional, and you can get full ready write permission in android 10, the solution is for andorid 11+

Comment: startActivityForResult is deprecated need alternatives.

Comment: After update application i am not able to access this folder again? is there i am missing anything?

Comment: On splash screen i grant this folder using "Use this folder" permission then delete it, after i copy fresh file into same folder again i am not able to read this fodler.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 10 with Scoped Storage if you are targeting to SDK 30 you can't access to others app's files even if they are in external storage, at least until you request and got the approval from Google to do so, specifically you will need [All Files Access Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files).

To know more see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjyYCUW-9tY&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers) video resource in YouTube from the official Android Developers channel.

You can temporary opt-out this restriction by setting your target SDK to 29 & using the **requestLegacyExternalStorage** flag to **true** in your app manifest, but you will need it to publish your app or app updates in the next November from this link about [Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk):

> Starting in November 2021, app updates will be required to target API
> level 30 or above and adjust for behavioral changes in Android 11.
> Existing apps that are not receiving updates are unaffected and can
> continue to be downloaded from the Play Store. Wear OS apps must
> continue to target API level 28 or higher.

**Note:** Before doing the request to get the approval from Google to get  [All Files Access Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files), see if your app really requires this permission, usually it was designed for apps that do files management or backups, and if your justifications is not good enough your request might be rejected.

Comment: i tried targeting sdk 29 still it does not work. (Other apps are using storage access framework with sdk 29, but i don't know anything about storage access framework)

Comment: Make sure you arre using requestLegacyExternalStorage = true in the app's Manifest file, also make sure you are requesting the appropriate permissions.